# java "terminate called without an active exception "

Tags: java, multithreading, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to multithread with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor but for somereason i keep on getting this error. Any idea what causes it and how to go about fixing it?

Thanks!

```
Memory: 732/732 2092/2092
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f43d2022e2b, pid=27273, tid=139927636702976
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libpthread.so.0+0xee2b]  raise+0x2b
#
```

Comment: Are you calling any native code?

Comment: Seems like a problem in JRE installation. I'd recommend to uninstall JRE and install newer version again. Build 20 is relatively old.

Comment: Do you have any hs_err_pid* files in the working direcyory of your application? They are generated on crashes like this and are sometimes helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using native code this error theoretically cannot happen. If it happens the problem is in JRE itself. So, uninstall JRE, then install the latest version and try again.

If it error still happens try to simplify your code, but anyway JRE is not expected to crash. So, if it happens after re-installation try the same on other machine. Probably such experiment may help you to locate where the problem is.

In any case you are welcome to report the issue to Oracle. They will happy to fix the bug. :)

Comment: I am making use of external libraries but I have no idea if it makes use of native code. Might that be the issue? 

My JRE worked fine with non concurrent processes though.